# WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime: [PIL] You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

This is a question from an absolute beginner of programing.

I tried the following codes on Google Colaboratory, and received the warning as written on the title of this post.

I restarted the runtime (which I believe worked successfully), but then when I retried the codes (by hitting 'run' button), I got the same warning.

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

```
!pip install torch torchvision
import torch
print('torch vision: ', torch.__version__)

!pip uninstall -y Pillow
!pip install Pillow==5.3.0
import PIL
print('pillow version: ', PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)
like so
```

Comment: it is only warning and don't bother it. OR maybe install `pillow` before `torch`. Maybe `torch` already imported `pillow` and this makes all problem. OR simply - first install all modules and later import them.

Comment: I wondering why you remove and install `pillow`. I checked code on Google Colab and it has already installed `pillow` `7.0.0` so you install older version and I don't understand why you do this.

Comment: Hi furas. Thank you very much for your comments! 

I have tried to install pillow before torch, but it it doesn't seem to work. 

The reason I uninstalled pillow and reinstalled it was because I was trying the codes from this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rW_PZI4B2I&list=WL&index=1

The question can be more general though. When a new version of a module doesn't work and I try to downgrade it (usually based on advise online), I always run into this issue.

Comment: Maybe Colab loads this module at start because it is popular module. But if I unistall existing version and install 5.3.0 and restart system then if I try uninstall again then it shows me that I try unistall 5.3.0 - so maybe you should uninstall existing version and install 5.3.0, next restart environment and next run code without installing 5.3.0 again because it can be already installed. Other thing: it is only warning and I wouldn't bother this and I would run rest of code. Eventually I would remove `pip install` so next time it will run it probably with `5.3.0`

Comment: this video is almost 1 year old and maybe 1 year ago version 5.3.0 was the newest version and maybe it needed the newest version - maybe it couldn't run with 5.2.0. Today I would try all this code with the newest torch and the newest pillow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to

- uninstall/install modules
- restart runtime
- run code without uninstall/install

---

But first I would try code with the newest modules - without unistalling/installing.

Your [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rW_PZI4B2I&list=WL&index=1) is almost 1 year old and maybe it needed `Pillow 5.3.0` at that momen. But it uses also `Torch 0.4.0` and today we have `1.7.0` and it may work correctly with `Pillow 7.0.0`

Comment: Thank you furas. You gave me precise and detailed explanation, and it worked! This is wonderful! I commented out the install and uninstall and the rest of the codes ran without a problem. I also appreciate you going through the tutorial video. I will try the latest version of Pillow for my own projects. This will help me a million for my future coding!